# Xcode switch producing breakpoint

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I am working on an XCode App project that contains a login/create-an-account page. In the create-an-account page, you have the option to choose either care-receiver or caregiver. However, when you click 'next', there seems to be a breakpoint. The code for the create-an-account page is linked below:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class CreateViewController: UIViewController {
    // define the elements
    @IBOutlet weak var address: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var phone: UITextField!
   
    @IBOutlet weak var receive: UISwitch!
    

    @IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    @IBAction func submit(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let email = email.text else { return }
        guard let password = password.text else { return }
        guard let phone = phone.text else { return }
        guard let address = address.text else { return }
        
        // authenticate the user
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { firebaseResult, error in
            if let e = error {
                print("Error during authentication: \(e.localizedDescription)")
            }
            else {
                let reciever=self.receive.isOn ? 1 : 0
                if(reciever==1){
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"submitter",sender:self)
                  
                }
                else{
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"caregive",sender:self)
                    
                }
                let ref = Database.database().reference()
                let collectionName = "Users" // Replace with your actual collection name
                let documentID = "user1"
                
               

                // Example: Reading data from a Firestore collection
                let data: [String: Any] = [
                    "Email": email,
                    "phone": phone,
                    "address": address,
                    "reciever":reciever
                ]

                // Use the `setData` method to write the document
                ref.child(collectionName).child(documentID).setValue(data) {(error, _) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error writing data: \(error)")
                    } else {
                        print("Data successfully written to the Realtime Database!")
                    }
                }
                
            }
            // fill data into the database
            //establish connection
            

            
          

            // Access the Firestore database
           

        }
        }
      

    
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

I tried putting print statements in the if condition for when receiver == 1 and for the corresponding else condition, but it wasn't successful.

Comment: It's unclear, is there a breakpoint, or a crash/deadlock? Are you seeing a error message in console? Is `let reciever=self.receive.isOn ? 1 : 0` called? Are you in main thread when calling `performSegue(withIdentifier:)`?

Comment: It is a breakpoint, so I am not seeing any 'error message' in the console.

Comment: Try some debugging... I assume by "click next" you mean tapping a button connected to `@IBAction func submit` ... set a breakpoint at the first line (`guard let email = ...`) and step through your code.

Comment: "breakpoint": Tap on the "play" then just above the console? It stops where exactly, There should be a highlighted line, with green or red banner?

Comment: With a green banner @Larme